# ElasticSearch time range query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have data in elastic search like this:

```
{
  id:"101",
  name: "note",
  startTime: "2017-01-01T20:00",
  endTime: "2017-02-02T20:00"
}
```

and I want to get documents where name is "note" and duration is covered.

EDIT:

Ok, so i got e.g. two documents

1. `{
     id:"101",
     name: "note",
     startTime: "2017-01-01T20:00",
     endTime: "2017-02-02T20:00"
   }`
2. `{ 
   id:"102", 
   name: "note", 
   startTime: "2017-01-01T22:00", 
   endTime: "2017-02-02T23:00" 
   }`

and now if I will get this second then I need to find all docs where time overlaps, we can see on this two docs that first and second will be "played" on the same time

Comment: What is stopping you from achieving it?